# Why aren't reviewers allowing people to fix this question?

Tags: support, rejected-edits

[Java: Why can we define a top level class as private?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913863/java-why-can-we-define-a-top-level-class-as-private)

It's very clear that the person intended to say "can't" instead of "can" (see the history), because of the sentence:

> Is there any other reason other than "We **can't** access a private class"?

Yet multiple edits are being [rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13679045) with reason "deviates from the original intent", probably because [the first approved edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1913863/timeline#history_c722ba7e-c89d-4857-a177-124c13c881b0) made it more misleading (it changed the title from "Can we..." to "Why can we..." implying we can).

The question is misleading, and it has a pretty good score.
What should people do in cases like this? Flag the post? Insist on editing and write a long comment explaining this? Depend on the original author? Post it on meta like I'm doing?

Comment: That suggested edit is 4 ***years*** old!

Comment: It already has answers that address the original question, including an accepted one.  It seems pretty clear to me that was the question the OP really wanted to ask.  Changing it to the opposite would invalidate the answers.  Nothing more to see here.

Comment: Is doesn't matter that it's old. It should be fixed. The only edit that made sense was the second.. The first was not good and the rollback shouldn't have happened. It should be rolled back to edition 3 with the Title "Why can't we define a top level class as private?". This edit will **not** invalidate any answers. It will just make the accepted answer confirm it.

Comment: Well, that would be useful.  Q: Why can't we define a top level class as private? A: Well, we can't.

Comment: You're right. There's a difference in "Why can't" that doesn't make sense. Then "Can we define a top level class as private?" :)

Comment: @Scratte: I made the edit, just to satisfy your OCD.  Now go check the stove.

Comment: @Scratte it being that old was more of an observation :p saying "multiple edits *are* being rejected" is kinda exaggerating if there's only been 1 in over 3 years

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thank you. It's off :)

Comment: @Scratte So, just to answer my last question (and based on votes to close it) I presume flagging would be a more appropriate action on cases like this, than posting on meta?

Comment: Next time I would probably suggest a new edit with a complete explanation including not invalidating answers. The "Comment: improved correctness" doesn't address the history. I don't know about the votes. I can't see them.

Comment: @geekley A flag (a custom mod flag, which is the only one that you could feasibly do) is almost 100% guaranteed to be declined, that's more for when stuff *can't* be done by users, whereas this is an edit which anyone >2k could have performed. The correct course of action is to post a suggested *with a detailed edit message*. If *that* gets declined then feel free to come to meta *to ask why* it was rejected, which should prompt the correct action where necessary. But remember that reviewers *are not supposed to have domain knowledge*, that is not their job

Comment: @geekley Side note: for future questions please keep in mind that "moderators" generally refer to elected moderators (one with diamond). None of the users involved in that question, including once reviewed the edit you've linked to are such.

Comment: OK, thanks for the explanations!

Comment: One of the answers say *"Java doesn’t allow a top level class to be private. Only 'public' or 'package'."*. Another says (my emphasis): *"A top-level class as private **would** be completely useless"*. A third (my emphasis): *"...call methods on a private top-level class (**if such a thing were allowed** by the language ... which it isn't!"*

Comment: @PeterMortensen I noticed. I also changed my opinion to "Can we define a top level class as private?" after the discrepancy of the accepted answer was pointed out :) I think my OCD is contagious.